# How to highlight brackets in bluefish?

Tags: bluefish

I'm using Bluefish on a Mac to write generic code (it's R but I just open Bluefish and start to type, I haven't told it what I am doing). The help says that Bluefish will:

"Highlighting matching block start and end markers (both brackets and tags)"

but it doesn't do this. So when I highlight a close bracket I'd like to see the open bracket highlighted above it. Under Document, Highlight Block Delimiters is ticked.

What am I doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't do it in plain text. You need to go Document, Language Mode and select a language (R is in the list).